# jQuery script not working properly on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have the following code that seems to not work in Google Chrome.

```
$("#productImg img").click(function() {
    var img = $(this).attr("src");
    var text = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#loader").show();
    $("#largeImg img").load(function() {
        $("#loader").hide();
    }).attr("src", img.replace('th_', 'si_'));
});
```

It works fine in Firefox, but doesn't in Chrome. If i click the first image it makes some kind of loop and never hides the `#loader`. You can test it [here](http://www.anpilinen.com/index.php?id=beddingSuppliesBlanketPique).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: No one is clicking through to your external site. Paste code/images here. If you want a demonstration, use a trusted site like [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an image is loaded you can use imagesLoaded (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)

```
var imgLoad = imagesLoaded("#largeImg img");
function onAlways( instance ) {
  console.log('all images are loaded');
}
imgLoad.on( 'always', onAlways );
```

Answer (score 0):

I make it work by comparing the 2 images

```
$("#productImg img").click(function(){
var img = $(this).attr("src");
var smallImage = $("#largeImg img").attr("src").replace('si_', 'th_');

if(img == smallImage){
    alert('match');
}else{
    alert('not a match');
}
```

});

Thanks to my friend Barbara Laird for saw my misspelling.